# change property on a class

Tags: javascript, xml, appcelerator

```
<View id="vContenedor" layout="">
    <Label id="lNumero"></Label>
    <TextField id="tFNumero" ></TextField>
    <View id="vNumero" class="lineas" ></View>
    <Label id="lFecha" ></Label>
    <TextField id="tFFecha" ></TextField>
    <View id="vFecha" class="lineas" ></View>
    <Label id="lCVV" ></Label>
    <TextField id="tFCVV" ></TextField>
    <View id="vCVV" class="lineas" ></View>
</View>
```

I want to change the the view's children, but I can't find the method to access the class. I tried with `className` it doesn't work anymore. I know that I can access via `$."id"` but I want to do with the class identifier or some singular.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change properties of a class in appcelerator titanium. Nor you can add a class dynamically. However you can create styles and add those to your elements, you can follow [this link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Dynamic_Styles-section-src-37530415_DynamicStyles-GenerateaDynamicStyle).

Comment: im sorry i was wrong... i want do something like this:
function cambia(){
for(var i in $.vContenedor.children){
   if($.vContenedor.children[i]."nameclass" == "lineas"){
....do this....
}
}
is there a way to do it?

Comment: post a snippet of your code so we know what you have tried.

Comment: f I understand you want to change elements that belong to a class. If I'm right I suggest you to use another property, for example `<Label class = "yourclass" isLine="true">` thus you can verify if the element belongs to the lineas class

Answer (score 0):

Since class property of any element is a multi-value property as it can contains references to any number of classes, hence it should never be used as a condition. Here's a recommended way of what you are trying to do or want to do:

**XML:**

```
    <View id="vContenedor" layout="">
        <Label id="lNumero" />
        <TextField id="tFNumero" />
        <View id="vNumero" class="lineas" customLine='1' />

        <Label id="lFecha" />
        <TextField id="tFFecha" />
        <View id="vFecha" class="lineas" />

        <Label id="lCVV" />
        <TextField id="tFCVV" />
        <View id="vCVV" class="lineas" customLine='0' />
    </View>
```

**JS:**
*Underscore way :)*

```
_.each($.vContenedor.children, function (tempChild) {
    if ( _.has(tempChild, 'customLine') ) {
        var custom = parseInt(tempChild.customLine);

        if (1 == custom) {
            // do run your code here....
        }
    }
});
```

Above code will run for all **View** elements which has **customeLine** property & with a value of 1.